# How could I somehow find out in which constructor I am in a class hierarchy?

Tags: oop, typescript

Let's say I have 3 TypeScript classes like this:

```
class A {
  A1 = "";
  A2 = 4;
  constructor() {}
}

class B extends A {
  B1 = "424";
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

class C extends B {
  C1 = false;
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

When I create an instance of A, B or C, I need to run some routines which loop through the properties of the object. Because of the design of TypeScript's constructor and field initializer logic, for example when I construct a B instance, at the end of the A constructor I don't have the B properties in my object yet. This leads me to ensure that this "field-looping stuff" initialization logic is called at and only at the bottom of the constructor chain.

So this led me to the question: when coding for example B's constructor, can I check somehow wether I am constructing a B instance, or is it a C? In the latter, I would skip the initialization logic and leave it the C constructor.

I hope the question and the motivation is understandable.

PS: I know that if I don't use field initializers anywhere, but initialize every field in the constructor BEFORE calling super(), then the problem goes away because at the top most level constructor in the end I would have all the fields needed. However, I like the syntax of field initializers, in such cases it produces a more readable, smaller code.

Comment: You shouldn't loop across the object properties until after the object is constructed.  Instead you can use a factory to construct the object, loop over its properties, then return the readied object.  The easiest and cleanest way of ensuring your logic gets called at the bottom of the constructor chain is to not call it inside the chain, but after the chain.

Comment: @Amy thank you for your comment, this is exactly how I am doing it right now, however I have some issues with the factory approach as well (don't want to get into that here, not related).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when coding for example B's constructor, can I check somehow wether I am constructing a B instance, or is it a C? In the latter, I would skip the initialization logic and leave it the C constructor

You can use the `constructor` property.

## Sample:

```
class A {
  A1 = "";
  A2 = 4;
  constructor() {
      if (this.constructor == A) this.loopAfterInit();
  }

  loopAfterInit(){console.log(Object.keys(this))}
}

class B extends A {
  B1 = "424";
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (this.constructor == B) this.loopAfterInit();
  }
}

class C extends B {
  C1 = false;
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (this.constructor == C) this.loopAfterInit();
  }
}


new A(); // A props logged
new B(); // A,B props logged
new C(); // A,B,C props logged
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've checked the generated __extend function several times, didn't catch this possibility.